# Scaler fullselct error

Tags: java, sql, database, db2

I have a sql delete query that requires two parameters in order to run.  When I run the query I get a:

```
com.web.command.exceptions.DatabaseException: The result of a scalar fullselect, SELECT INTO statement, or VALUES INTO statement is more than one row.. SQLCODE=-811, SQLSTATE=21000, DRIVER=4.14.111
```

My query is:

```
delete from RESETPASSWORD where planner = (select planner from g_secure where planner = ucase(?) or lcase(email) = lcase(?))
```

The java I use to set up the delete is:

```
public boolean deleteByPlannerAndEmail(String planner, String email) throws DatabaseException{
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    try {
        conn = dataAccess.grabConnection("system", "ResetPasswordDAO.deleteByPlanner(planner)");

        ps = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_DELETE_BY_PLANNER);

        ps.setString(1, planner);
        ps.setString(2, email);

        ps.executeUpdate();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DatabaseException(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        dataAccess.release(conn, ps,null);
    }

    return true;

}
```

How do I get the query to delete all rows with the same planner not just one row?
Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete multiple rows, change `where planner = (...)` to `where planner IN (...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured my question out so just posting in case anyone has same problem.  The = only returns one row but I wanted to return multiple rows so I had to change the query to

```
delete from resetpassword where planner in (select planner from g_secure where planner = ucase(?) or lcase(email) = lcase(?))
```

now I return multiple rows and not just one.